# 24 inch chrome BMX with serial number starting with CR? The forks are stamped GT but top tube does not go past top tube. Definitely an older BMX?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]Hey everyone I have old school 24 inch Chrome BMX with serial numbers beginning with CR99. I thought it was a original GT but the top tube doesn’t go past the seat. The forks are the only thing stamped as GT with the chrome being the same all through the bike and the serial number stamped by the rear wheel dropout. Anyone know what type of BMX I have?

Comment: Gonna need some good pictures

Comment: The description is a good start, but pictures (several) would be a big help with this question in order to get an accurate answer.